# UK extended keyboard layout

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a bit of an arcane question about a specific keyboard layout.  It's the Windows XP SP2+ keyboard layout that is called "United Kingdom Extended".

I love most of the layout, but there is one annoying thing: it turns backtick (`) into a 'dead key'.  Why they made this decision I don't know, because every other dead key involves pressing AltGr along with it, i.e. if you don't press AltGr, the keyboard functions as before.  I wish this behaviour applied to backtick as well, so to get a grave e, I'd press AltGr+`, then e.

Does anyone know how I can do this?  Whether it's possible in Windows itself or whether it can be done using some other software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MSKLC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) to create your own keyboard layouts.

I made [eurokb](http://www.doxdesk.com/software/win/eurokb.html) with it, which you may find fits your needs. I share your loathing for non-alted dead keys.

Comment: This is an excellent tool, thank you!  I made an 'enhanced' UK extended layout which uses alt-ctrl-comma as the grave accent dead key, and restores the old backtick functionlaity.  If anyone's interested, it's available at: http://www.game-point.net/misc/keyboard%20layout%20-%20uk%20extended%20enhanced.zip

Answer (score 1):

If you press the backtick key followed by <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, the backtick will be inserted.

This is true also of any other accent key that functions as a dead key.

Comment: Yep, but it's still annoying that any key is a dead key, by default, at all.  You should always need to press ctrl-alt to trigger a dead key.

Comment: yeah, well, that's just, like, your opinion, man